# How to crop the object detected using YOLO in R?

Tags: r

I have detected the object in an image using YOLO. But I need to save the detected object only into another file.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please read - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In your case, we are missing reproducible data and/or desired outcomes.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO.

(-1)
lol